# How to set id to an element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I am creating x amount of image boxes using jquery `append()` function with all having the same class name, But now I need to set each box id to `i`. for avoiding confusion this is what I mean:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    $('.d').append('<img src="" class="UP__" width="120" height="120">');
    $('.d img').attr("id",i);
}
```

The problem with above code i'm facing is that it sets all 10 `img` boxes `id` to `10`, But I need to set first box id to `1`, second to `2` and so on.

My question is how to set each element id to value of `i`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in the append method you can use concatination like :  $('.d').append('<img src="" class="UP__" id='"+i+"' width="120" height="120">');

Comment: IDs shouldn't be numeric. Do something like `i1`, `i2`....

Comment: fiddle for demo for future users https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/dreg2j4g/

Comment: updated  to show ids https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/f4d3jgbd/

Answer (score 3):

Just add id to img tag

`$('.d').append('<img src="" id="'+i+'" class="UP__" width="120" height="120">');`

Answer (score 1):

First declare your variables (whether using `var` or `let`) in order to avoid created global variables, and then you can either add the `id` within the loop:

```
for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    $('.d').append('<img src="" id="' + i + '" class="UP__" width="120" height="120">');
}
```

Or do so outside of the loop:

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
    $('.d').append('<img src="" class="UP__" width="120" height="120">');
}

// here we select all the matching <img> elements, and update
// 'id' property using the prop() method, and the anonymous
// function:
$('.d img').prop('id', function (index){
  // 'index' is the index of the current element in
  // the jQuery collection over which prop() iterates:
  return index;
});
```

The problem with your posted approach was that you were selecting all the matching elements (in each iteration of the loop) and setting the `id` of all those elements to the same number. This is avoided by both approaches shown above.

Note that using a numeric character as the first character of an `id` does complicate the CSS selectors used to target those `id`s as you first need to escape the number character.

With that in mind, to select the element with `id="1"` you'd need to use:

```
#\31 {
  /* css */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give an **ID**. Just use each function of jQuery.

I added the images manually, but you can make it of course dynamic using your own code.

```
<div class="d">
  <img src="http://afterishtar.pl/images/100x100.gif">
  <img src="http://afterishtar.pl/images/100x100.gif">
  <img src="http://afterishtar.pl/images/100x100.gif">
  <img src="http://afterishtar.pl/images/100x100.gif">
  <img src="http://afterishtar.pl/images/100x100.gif">
</div>
```

Then this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".d img").each(function( index ) {
    console.log(index);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are adding the id to all img tags inside the .d div.

PS: Always have the image src tag properly set. An empty src for image tag  creates a lot of problems than it solves. if src is not known or set later, use about_blank.

Also, its always a good recommendation to change the dom as minimal times as possible. When possible, append newly created elements once all the manipulations are complete and before attaching them to DOM.

```js
$(function() {

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var $img = $('<img src="about_blank" class="UP__" width="120" height="120">');
    $img.attr("id", i).attr("title", i);

    $('.d').append($img);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d"></div>
```